# ND Blob support caffe: legacy accessors fail for blobs > 4 axes

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

I am getting an error when executing following `.prototxt` and I have absolutely no idea why I get an error there:

```
layer {
    name: "conv"
    type: "Convolution"
    bottom: "image"
    top: "conv"
    convolution_param {
        num_output: 2
        kernel_size: 5
        pad: 2
        stride: 1
        weight_filler {
            type: "xavier"
        }
        bias_filler {
            type: "constant"
            value: 0
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error output. As I have seen in the latest `caffe-master-branch` it should be possible to use `5D-Blobs`.

```
I1202 14:54:58.617269  2393 hdf5_data_layer.cpp:93] Number of HDF5 files: 9
I1202 14:54:58.631134  2393 hdf5.cpp:35] Datatype class: H5T_INTEGER
I1202 14:54:59.159739  2393 net.cpp:150] Setting up train-data
I1202 14:54:59.159760  2393 net.cpp:157] Top shape: 1 1 1 128 128 (16384)
I1202 14:54:59.159765  2393 net.cpp:157] Top shape: 1 1 8 128 128 (131072)
I1202 14:54:59.159766  2393 net.cpp:165] Memory required for data: 589824
I1202 14:54:59.159773  2393 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer down_level_0_conv
I1202 14:54:59.159790  2393 net.cpp:100] Creating Layer down_level_0_conv
I1202 14:54:59.159795  2393 net.cpp:434] down_level_0_conv <- image
I1202 14:54:59.159804  2393 net.cpp:408] down_level_0_conv -> down_level_0_conv
F1202 14:54:59.159915  2393 blob.hpp:140] Check failed: num_axes() <= 4 (5 vs. 4) Cannot use legacy accessors on Blobs with > 4 axes.
```

Do I need to go to a certain branch? I just pulled from `caffe-master-branch` again to make sure it is the newest version. I then made a make clean make all command and it still does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, this error comes from the `"Xavier"` filler: this filler computes the ratio between the input and output channels. If you replace it with a different filler you should be Okay with ND blob.

Comment: Seems @thigi can choose a `GaussianFiller`.

Answer (score 1):

As a complement of [Shai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40956354/6281477), in order to be compatible with the `ND Convolution` and `InnerProduct` layer, the "`Xavier`" filler [code](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/include/caffe/filler.hpp#L144)

```
virtual void Fill(Blob<Dtype>* blob) {
...
int fan_in = blob->count() / blob->num();
int fan_out = blob->count() / blob->channels();
Dtype n = fan_in;  // default to fan_in
...
Dtype scale = sqrt(Dtype(3) / n);
caffe_rng_uniform<Dtype>(blob->count(), -scale, scale,
        blob->mutable_cpu_data());
CHECK_EQ(this->filler_param_.sparse(), -1)
         << "Sparsity not supported by this Filler.";
}
```

in caffe, should be more like this:

```
...
int fan_in = blob->count() / blob->shape(0);
int fan_out = blob->num_axis() == 2 ? blob->shape(0) : blob->count() / blob->shape(1);
...//original stuff
```

This little change should also make your prototxt work.

Comment: @Shai Ok, I'll give it a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When I remove the check in `line 140 blob.hpp` it does work. This is one way to solve it, not the best one though.

(But this cannot be the proper solution. Is there anything else?)